# finding derived classes in source code

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a file containing python code.  I need to inspect it (*without* importing or running it, though compiling it is ok).

I want to get Classes declared in the file and see if they are derived from a certain base class.

for example,

say in my 'foo' module, I have a class defined named 'Bar', that is derived from class 'Foo':

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

class Bar(Foo)
    pass
```

then I have an external python source file, such as:

```
from foo import Bar

class Baz(Bar):
    pass
```

I want to inspect the source to know if the file contains any class definitions that are derived from my 'Foo'.

Do I need to parse the AST?  Is that the right direction to statically analyze this for subclass definitions?

Comment: What do you mean "without importing ..., though compiling it is ok"?  What do you mean when you say compile?

Comment: If this is a one-off, can't you just use `grep` and then review by hand? Or am I misunderstanding what you're trying to do?

Comment: mgilson, meaning it's ok to use python's compile() or ast.parse().

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg -- Thanks.  I just wanted to be clear what you meant by that.  Basically you don't want to execute any of the code -- presumably because you're getting it from an untrusted source.

Comment: it's part of unittest framework that loads test scripts for execution.  I need something that asserts a file is valid before I use unittest LoadTests* or Discover.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you mean by 'valid'?  I'm not seeing why something much simpler, like `try/except`ing the `import` and `inspect`ing the module after import for members matching your criteria wouldn't work.  Besides, even then, you can't be sure that a given module won't have a member of a given type or description until after it's been processed during import; it could, for instance, have a member generated by a class factory that wouldn't be identifiable by just parsing the text.

Comment: sr2222.. I can't import because that will cause side effects in this case.

Comment: @sr2222, I'm not worried about dynamically created classes.. just what's defined in the file.

Comment: What sort of sideeffects?  Is mocking/monkeypatching the interfaces that will be side-effected prior to analyzing your targets, or somehow otherwise sandboxing the candidate modules an option?

Answer (score 1):

An answer that doesn't compile the code would be to use [pysmell](https://code.google.com/p/pysmell/) or similar.

Given:

```
# base.py
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class First(Base):
    def __init__(self, name="first"):
        super(First, self).__init__(name)


class Second(First):
    def __init__(self, name="second"):
        super(Second, self).__init__(name)

class Third(Second):
    def __init__(self, name="third"):
        super(Third, self).__init__(name)

t = Third()
```

running `pysmell base.py` generates a PYSMELLTAGS file looking like:

```
{'CLASSES': {'base.Base': {'bases': ['object'],
                           'constructor': ['name'],
                           'docstring': '',
                           'methods': [],
                           'properties': ['name']},
             'base.First': {'bases': ['base.Base'],
                            'constructor': ["name='first'"],
                            'docstring': '',
                            'methods': [],
                            'properties': []},
             'base.Second': {'bases': ['base.First'],
                             'constructor': ["name='second'"],
                             'docstring': '',
                             'methods': [],
                             'properties': []},
             'base.Third': {'bases': ['base.Second'],
                            'constructor': ["name='third'"],
                            'docstring': '',
                            'methods': [],
                            'properties': []}},
 'CONSTANTS': ['base.t'],
 'FUNCTIONS': [],
 'HIERARCHY': ['base'],
 'POINTERS': {}}
```

Which I believe would help the OP achieve their goal of recognising classes derived from other classes.

Answer (score -1):

I thought something like this would be OK as it only pollutes `x`.

```
import inspect
from tester import Test

x = __import__("something", globals={}, locals={})

for (n,v) in inspect.getmembers(x):
    if inspect.isclass(v):
        print "CLASS:", n, inspect.getmro(v)
        if Test != v and Test in inspect.getmro(v):
            print "FOUND:", n, v


 #something.py
 from tester import Test
 class SomeClass(Test): pass


 #tester.py
 class Test(object): pass
```

Output:

```
CLASS: SomeClass (<class 'something.SomeClass'>, <class 'tester.Test'>, <type 'object'>)
FOUND: SomeClass <class 'something.SomeClass'>
CLASS: Test (<class 'tester.Test'>, <type 'object'>)
```

Comment: That executes something.py, which the OP seems to be avoiding. Maybe something.py is untrusted code.

Comment: Yeah I hesitated for a long time until the OP said ``I'm not worried about dynamically created classes.. just what's defined in the file`` then I thought using ``__import__`` would stop that happening. Although I reserve the right to be totally wrong, which often happens when second guessing.